# How to automatically sync s3 bucket to a local folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Im trying to have a replica of my s3 bucket in a local folder. it should be updated when a change occurs on the bucket.
I see many options to do it using lambda functions but im asking about the usage of s3 cli command:

```
aws s3 sync s3://my-bucket . --delete
```

which will download any files exists on the bucket, and also delete local files that exists locally but missing from the bucket (expected behavior).

Is there any problem to loop it forever with few sec of delay, like?

```
while true; do aws s3 sync s3://my-bucket . --delete; sleep 3s; done
```

Is there any limitation of the number of api calls i can do per second ? is there a better solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you on linux? You could stick your command in a shell script and run it as a cronjob

```
* * * * * /path/to/your/script
```

^ Runs every minute

```
*/10 * * * * /path/to/your/script
```

^ Runs every 10 minutes

That would be much more reliable than a bash script in a loop.

Comment: I wish it was linux... anyway, i also prefer cron/scheduler over loop .... but the question is about the usage of the command... anyway in both ways, there is a need to check if the process from last iteration is still running before invoking another process in parallel. in both ways cron/loop I should handle it in the same manner